# IdentityServer4 - is it possible to use local login form with external provider and no round trip?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I'm trying to use a local login form to authenticate a user credentials against its external provider (Azure Active Directory).

I understand that, per client, you can enable local login. That helps, as when set to true, I'll get the local login form but but I'm still unclear as to how to fire off the middle ware for that external provider. Is there a way to send client credentials to the external provider to receive an ID token? My current code redirects to the Microsoft login; and then back to my identity server, and then the client application. I want the user to login in through identity server but not have them know it's really authenticating against Azure.

Here's my start up:

```
        var schemeName = "Azure-AD";
        var dataProtectionProvibder = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
        var distributedCache = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();
        var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(
            typeof(OpenIdConnectMiddleware).FullName,
            typeof(string).FullName, schemeName,
            "v1");
        var dataFormat = new CachedPropertiesDataFormat(distributedCache, dataProtector);

        ///
        /// Azure AD Configuration
        /// 
        var clientId = Configuration["AzureActiveDirectory:ClientId"];
        var tenantId = Configuration["AzureActiveDirectory:TenantId"];
        Redirect = Configuration["AzureActiveDirectory:TenantId"];

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = schemeName,
            DisplayName = "Azure-AD",
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}",
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            StateDataFormat = dataFormat,
        });

        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

This is the login.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    var context = this.HttpContext.Authentication;
    List<AuthenticationDescription> schemes =  context.GetAuthenticationSchemes().ToList();

    returnUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });

    // start challenge and roundtrip the return URL
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = returnUrl,
        Items = { { "scheme", provider } }
    };

    //await HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync(provider, props);

    return new ChallengeResult(provider, props);         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion ,we shouldn't directly pass the username/password directly from other Idp to azure AD for authentication as a security implementation .And even Azure AD supports the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant ,it's only available in native client. I suggest you keep the normal way and don't mix them .